# How to Sort Collection Fields by Name & Letter in Meteor JS?

Tags: javascript, sorting, meteor

How to Sort Collection Fields by Name & Letter in `Meteor JS`? means

- A Collection contains 3 fields , they are fname,id & email.
- Sorting based on fname or fname letters for ex:fname = xyz , sort using `x` means x is a letter of fname.

  Please see the below code and suggest me what to do for above?

Code :

```
Template.client.clientname = function () 
 {
   //here Client is collection name & fname is field.           
   return Client.find();
   //return Client.find({name: {$fname: /k$/}});
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You use sort and order the keys in the order of your preference. There's more details about this in the docs:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/
- http://docs.meteor.com/#sortspecifiers

So:

```
Client.find({}, {sort:{fname: 1, id:1, email: 1}});
```

1 means in ascending order (A-Z) and -1 in descending order (Z-A).

Comment: No , Actually i need to display particular letter names only for example 100 names are there and it contains 'x' only 25 is there.So in this time i sort by 'x' then i get only that 25 names only.So what i can do for this?.@Akshat.